# Check engine light mysteriously turned off

Tags: engine, cel, misfire, lights, cylinder

I had a check engine light indicator turned ON this morning. I took it to AutoZone to get the code for the CEL and got a cylinder misfire on two of my cylinders. When I started my car back up the CEL indicator did not turn ON. I've driven 20 miles since then thinking everything is fine, but now I'm doubting that thought. I'm wondering what could've caused the light to have turned OFF? Should I be worried? Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the AutoZone person cleared the codes, the light won't come back on. Usually, when a CEL occurs, I'll clear the codes and see if they come back. If they don't come back, then I'm wary of the item, but I'm less worried about it. If it doesn't come back on, there's no real need to worry about it.

This is completely normal behavior for the CEL as described. I would not be worried about it.